# "She has punched a girl three times" — three different girls or the same one girl?

Tags: meaning

**Example 1**
He has killed a person three times.

1. He killed three different people.
2. He killed the same person three times.

**Example 2**
She has punched a girl three times.

1. She has punched three different girls.
2. She has punched the same girl three times.

I think both Example 1 and Example 2 can be interpreted in two ways. Is that correct?

Comment: The phrase format can be interpreted both ways, yes, but in the first example, one of the possible interpretations is somewhat ruled out just by common sense.

Comment: Example 1, 2) does not exist except in fantasy fiction. So, no, your first example is inaccurate.

Comment: @TKoL Not if you're playing a game, acting in a performance, dreaming, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a purely semantic ambiguity which is practically of no consequence, but there are phrases which can be constructed that have two perfectly reasonable interpretations. One example of this would be

> Every boy gave a girl a rose.

Depending on the context, this could mean that either every boy gave a single girl a rose, or that there are multiple girls who each received a rose from a boy. Specifically, this constitutes a [scope ambiguity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(formal_semantics)#Scope_ambiguity)